# Visual studio code catching syntax errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using Visual studio code for coding Nodejs. I very strange and annoying that almost everything I write passes until runtime it fails.

For example, I wrote this code

```
function validateRentalReturn(rental) {
    const schema = Joi.object({
        customerId: Joi.objectId().required,
        movieId: Joi.objectId().required
    });
    return schema.validate(rental);
}
```

and I forgot to add `()` at the end of `required()` and it didn't complain or anything until at run time I called this method and I started getting the following error `"movieId" failed custom validation because Cannot read property 'presence' of undefined`.

I had no clue about this error but finally got it sorted, in the intellisense it shows like following

[image]

Now how should i know that `required` is a `property` or a `function`. Can someone kindly guide how i can get proper Intellisense and error handling for Node js code in VS code.

Comment: That's *not* an error from a static perspective. It's a defined property; the fact that it *could* be called isn't relevant to the IDE (maybe you *wanted* to pass a reference to the method).

Comment: What you are describing is not a syntax error. JavaScript is not a strongly typed language so it can be executed as is.

Comment: But what does ``abc``on the left of ``required`` is describing, is it a property or a function?

Comment: VSCode needs the typings for the library in question to know that. They ship as a separate package because someone else than the author derived them. Try running `npm i -D @types/joi` and see if your editing experience improves.

Comment: Its still the same after installing types/joi. Still ``abc`` is coming instead of property or function

Comment: Please post your code instead of an image. You are asking questions in regards to `abc` but there is no `abc` shown in your image or code snippet.

Comment: I just tried with the same library (assuming this is importing `@hapi/joi`), and I do see type information even without installing the typings. Based on your screenshot, there is something wrong with your VSCode. `module.exports` and `Date` should at least be a different colour. If you go to Help->About do all the version numbers look reasonable? Is anything broken if you look at the TypeScript logs under OUTPUT in the bottom panel?

Comment: Do you have a jsconfig or tsconfig in the project? Could be related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/26550

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Typescript instead of vanilla Javascript. Its pretty much the same in syntax, but its a typed version of Javascript. Apart from that, a linter is also useful for this kind of things. For typescript you would use TSlint, but you can use ESlint for pure javascript.
Hope this helps!